# How Can I Set the Default Encoding of the Windows Console to UTF-8

Tags: encoding, utf-8

As the title asked, right-click on the window caption only provide encoding 436 and 937(i'm a Chinese so forgive my broken English), is there any way to add "UTF-8" or "65001" to the options? Input chcp.com 65001 every time is so annoying...
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shortcut with the option /k "chcp 65001" to start a utf-8 console.
e.g.

```
cmd.exe /u /k "chcp 65001"
```