# Printing special characters to the Windows console in C++

Tags: c++, console-application, extended-ascii

After 2 hours of searching and trying various methods, I'm pulling my hair out trying to print special ascii characters to the console! (C++)

```
typedef unsigned char UCHAR;

int main()
{
  UCHAR c = '¥';
  cout << c;

  return 0;
}
```

Why does this code print Ñ (209) instead of ¥ (165)???

I've tried:

```
SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8);
SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
```

but neither seems to do anything, no matter which values I pass to it.

Someone else suggested that the console's font needed to be changed through the registry. But that's ridiculous. I don't want my end users to have to start changing registry values simply to run my program...

the really odd thing is that if I print all the ascii characters to a file (using ofstream), they show up correctly both in notepad, and the visual studio editor (2012 professional).

```
ofstream file("ASCII.txt");;
if (file.is_open())
{
    UCHAR c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        c++;
        file << c << "\t|\t" << (int)c << endl;
    }
}
file.close();
```

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I bet the `type` command does the same as your program.  Open a command-line window and issue a `type ASCII.txt` and see what gets outputted to the console.

Comment: Research the internet for "Microsoft code pages".

Comment: Character 165 is illegal in UTF-8. The high-most bit is set which means it is a continuation character comprising 2+ bytes.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm unfamiliar with the type command, and a cursory google search only returned results for the expected "typeof" and "typedef" functions. I feel like you may have misread my question. That code section at the bottom was only for testing what the actual ascii values were. I don't intend to use it in my final program.

Comment: @BenSeawalker He means the DOS `type` command.

Comment: What do you have for your Character Set in Properties -> General -> Project Defaults -> Character Set?

Comment: @BenSeawalker My directions stated `Open a command-line window`  Are you familiar with the command window?  It's the window with the `C:\>` prompt in it (or similar)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I apologize, I missed the "Open a command-line window" part. >_<

Comment: @kfsone It was set to unicode. I changed it to multibyte, but still no difference in console.

Comment: @BenSeawalker ok. no problem. If `type` gives the same output as your program, then the issue is a matter of setting the console code page, which others have mentioned.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I also tried SetConsoleOutputCP(1250) to no effect.

Comment: What is the encoding of your source file?

Comment: @BenSeawalker Forget the program for a moment, and try to get `type` to work (assuming it behaves the same as your program).  There is a `chcp` command -- try to use that to get `type` to work correctly.  Once you find the right code page, then go back to your program and attempt to do the same with `SetConsoleOutputCP`.

Comment: @kfsone N/A I'm simply trying to directly print '¥'

Comment: @BenSeawalker Seems like `chcp 65001` changes the console to UTF-8, as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470271/how-can-i-set-the-default-encoding-of-the-windows-console-to-utf-8  So maybe you should specify `65001` as the code page?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks for the help. My current console codepage is 437 (OEM United States) type only prints the first 25 lines of a given txt file. "help type" says it only takes a filename as a parameter, so there's no -all, /full, etc. to display the whole file.

Comment: "¥" is not 165 in cp(437). Hence why it matters what encoding your source file is in. DUH.

Comment: @kfsone there's no need for that. In any case, I've tried SetConsoleCP() and SetConsoleOutputCP() with every code found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx none of which affected the output in any way. I also opened cmd used "dhcp 1252" and ran my program from that window rather than the VS debugger, and still no change.

Comment: Intended the 'DUH' at myself for not catching it sooner, sorry :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the pain of encoding :(

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows>

int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(437);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(437);
    std::cout << (char)157 << "\n";
}
```

Generates:

[image: Compilation and execution result]

The problem is that your source file is *not* in CP437 and therefore the character has a different value than the one you are trying to print (as you noted, in your source value is is 165 which is a different character in CP437).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437

Comment: `SetConsoleCP(437);
 SetConsoleOutputCP(437);

 cout << '¥';` still prints 'Ñ' :(

Comment: oh well, thanks for the help. Could you post a link to the site you got your ascii codes from? All the ones I've seen state that char is "190" not "157"

Comment: It's at the end of the answer. `cout << '¥';` works for me if I save the file with CP 437 encoding.

Comment: I saved all my .cpp and .h files with 437 encoding, and cleaned/rebuilt the project. still no effect. :(

Comment: Nevermind. I restarted VS and now it all works flawlessly! Thanks @kfsone I never would have thought to change the encoding of my source files. haha

Answer (score 1):

> Why does this code print Ñ (209) instead of ¥ (165)???

It doesn't work because some of your source, literal and console encodings don't match.

To correctly display Unicode characters (note that `¥` is not [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)) in C++23 you can use [`std::print`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/print):

```cpp
#include <print>

int main () {
  std::print("¥");
}
```

Until `std::print` is widely available you can use the open-source {fmt} library, it is based on ([godbolt](https://www.godbolt.org/z/rqMqb8a89)):

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>

int main () {
  fmt::print("¥");
}
```

Just make sure that your literal encoding is UTF-8 which is normally the default on most platforms and on Windows/MSVC is enabled with `/utf-8`.

This is more reliable than using legacy codepages such as CP437 because it doesn't depend on the global state that you don't always control. You also don't need to use nonportable APIs to change console codepage.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt} and C++23 `std::print`.

Answer (score -1):

I have a working code on MSVS Windows 11.
The point is you need to tell to the compiler, that:

1. You want to describe/enter a character typed as u8"\uxxx ..."
   or u8"" , (copy/paste), or  u8"\U0001F600"
   coded as UTF-8.
   For that you need to enter in the developer command line:
   chcp 65001 Enter
   You will see: Active code page: 65001.
   Alternativity you live the code page as it is,
   You type chcp on cmd and you might see:
   Active code page: 1250
   But you need to compile with:
   cl /W4 /EHsc /source-charset:utf-8 mbs_extended.cpp mbs_extended.cpp
   so that your code u8"\uxxx ..."
   or u8"" , (copy/paste), or  u8"\U0001F600" , will be translated into a sequence of char that will be translated as numbers/codes in UTF-8, stored in
   the char *s provided.
   When printing that char*, because you used chcp 65001 Enter, the output will be translated into the desired unicode chars.
   You can play with the code above, read carefully the comments.

   `//cl /W4 /EHsc /source-charset:utf-8 /execution-charset:utf-8, if after chcp Enter, Active code page is: 1250 -> This will change chcp active code to: 65001
   // When you type chcp Enter in your Developer Command Line your output can be: Active code page: 1250, or other.
   // If you type chcp 65001 Enter you get Active code page: 65001
   // So if in cmd you type first: chcp 65001, you can compile using the below line:
   //cl /W4 /EHsc /source-charset:utf-8 mbs_extended.cpp mbs_extended.cpp

//Execution (output) charset is decided when you type in cmd chcp 65001, or if Active code page is:1250 when you compile with: cl.../execution-charset:utf-8...

```
#include <iostream>

#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    
    // SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    // If you compile with: cl /W4 /EHsc /source-charset:utf-8 mbs_extended.cpp mbs_extended.cpp and Active code page: 1250, -> Uncomment line before, and surprise:
    // At the end of Program,
    // Active code page: 1250
    const char *text = u8"This text is in UTF-8. ¡Olé! 佻\n";
    std::cout << text;
    
    char *s = u8"\u2193";  //universal code name for: ↓
                           // might be possible to use char8_t specially designed for UTF-8 if compile with /std:c++20 or latest
    printf("\nSymbol: %s\n", s);
    printf("  length: %zu\n", strlen(s));
    size_t sz0 = strlen(s);
    cout << "Arrow hexcode: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < sz0; i++)
    {
        printf("%X ", (unsigned char) s[i] );
    }
    cout << endl;
    
    char *s1 = u8"";
    printf("\nSymbol: %s\n", s1);
    size_t sz = strlen(s1);
    printf("  length: %zu\n", strlen(s1));
    
    cout << "Smiley hexcode: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    {
        printf("%X ", (unsigned char) s1[i] );
    }
    cout << endl;
    
    
    char *s2 = u8"\U0001F600";  //universal code name for:  See the difference between: u8"\U0001F600" and u8"\u2193" (UTF-32 vs UTF-16), (8 vs 4)
                                // /source-charset:utf-8 and the Prefix u8
    printf("\nSymbol: %s\n", s2);
    size_t sz1 = strlen(s2);
    printf("  length: %zu\n", strlen(s2));
    
    cout << "Smiley hexcode: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < sz1; i++)
    {
        printf("%X ", (unsigned char) s2[i] );
    }
    cout << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
// If you uncomment SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8); , Remember, Active code page was: 1250 and you did'nt modify with chcp in cmd line.
// So either chcp 65001 in cmd line either SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8), either cl.../execution-charset:utf-8
// After program finish execution,
// Active code page: 65001 (UTF-8), 
//(multi byte string), (one or more 2 or 3 bytes, for characters)
// This is the work of SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);`
```