# Compiled program can't display special characters

Tags: c++, setlocale

Currently I'm trying to display some portuguese characters in C++, in VS code terminal it displays fine but when I run the .exe  file it displays abnormaly. Can someone please help me! Thanks in advance! :)

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
using namespace std;

int add(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}
int subtract(int a, int b){
    return a - b;
}
int multiplication(int a, int b){
    return a * b;
}
int division(int a, int b){
    return a / b;
}

main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    float n1, n2;
    cout << "Número 1: ";
    cin >> n1;
    cout << "Número 2: ";
    cin >> n2;
    cout << "Soma: " << add(n1, n2) << "\n";
    cout << "Subtração: " << subtract(n1, n2) << "\n";
    cout << "Multiplicação: " << multiplication(n1, n2) << "\n";
    cout << "Divisão: " << division(n1, n2) << "\n";
}
```

In C++ btw.

I tried to import locale.h library and used the line `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");` inside of `main()`, I want to display special characters.

Comment: Just FYI, you should use `<clocale>` instead of `<locale.h>` ... As to your issue, from memory, this is usually an issue with the console's setting. Not sure if you're using Windows, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31083573/c-printing-special-ascii-characters-to-the-windows-console might help if so.

Comment: Works on my machine.  I'm using macOS Sonoma 14.1.2.  Are you using macOS, Linux, or Amiga OS?

Comment: @Eljay Lmao, Amiga OS? I'm surprised you didn't say Temple OS. I'm using Windows 11.

Comment: I think you'll need to make sure everything in the I/O pipeline is configured for either UTF-8 (my preference), or UTF-16, or Portuguese (Windows 1252).  If anything in the I/O pipeline is differently configured, then the output will turn out mojibake.